# ArrayList adding item error Android (Eclipse)

Tags: java, android, arrays, eclipse, arraylist

i'm making a project, I've a method that is based to parentHead array, selects each item in the ArrayList v (that contains objects of class Voce) that have property that match with the current parentHead array's item, and put them in another arrayList, in turn added to another arrayList.
In a nutshell there is an arraylist (item) that contain many arraylist, each of which contain many object of class Voce.
The problem is that when i add the arraylist with the objects "Voce" to the main arraylist (item) all the elements present in the arraylist "item" are overwritten with the arraylist that i'm adding, so item[0]=item[1]=item[2]...=item[i]
From what can be caused this?
Thanks

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Voce>> prepareListData(ArrayList<Voce> v)
{
    int j=0,i=0;

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Voce>> item=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Voce>>();
    ArrayList<Voce> temp=new ArrayList<Voce>();
    String stringa;

    for(i=0;i<parentHead.length;i++)
    {
        temp.clear();

        if(parentHead[i].compareTo(" ")!=0)
        {
          for(j=0;j<v.size();j++)
          {
            stringa=""+v.get(j).getMese()+"/"+v.get(j).getAnno();

            if(stringa.compareTo(parentHead[i])==0)
            temp.add(v.get(j));
          }

          if(temp.size()!=0)
          item.add(temp);
        }
        else
        i=parentHead.length;
    }

    return item;
}
```

Comment: You're constantly working with the same list, this list is a fixed object in your memory, how do you expect it to be different each round? Create a `new ArrayList<>()` each time and you'll be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a single array list in `temp` that you repeatedly fill and clear.

You need a new array list to add to the "outer" array list; you can't reuse them like this.

E.g., instead of `temp.clear()` you want `temp = new ArrayList<Voce>()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`new ArrayList`** for adding into the **`outer ArrayList`**.

When you clear your inner arrayList then your added arraylist to outer one is actually getting cleared.

In Shot do it like this,

```
ArrayList<Voce> temp=null;   // earlier new ArrayList<Voce>();
String stringa;

for(i=0;i<parentHead.length;i++)
{
   temp=new ArrayList<Voce>();  // earlier temp.clear();

   if(parentHead[i].compareTo(" ")!=0)
   {
      for(j=0;j<v.size();j++){
         stringa=""+v.get(j).getMese()+"/"+v.get(j).getAnno();

         if(stringa.compareTo(parentHead[i])==0)
            temp.add(v.get(j));
   }

   if(temp.size()!=0)
       item.add(temp);
   }else
        i=parentHead.length;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works :) I've tried to use a new allocation but did not want to works .-. maybe I was wrong in something.
However thanks :)